# Is Napaka's Scepter from TOA a permanent magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, tomb-of-annihilation

Specifically when it comes to Adventurers League magic item count.

Comment: This is the one that is used to dust the stone golem?

Comment: It's on TOA p. 165, under the "Sarcophagus" section below "Treasure" for room 53, Crypt of the Sun Queen.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Also, it can't be taken with at the end of the adventure.

### From DDAL FAQ

While this applied to nonmagical items, it does indicate that treasure and equipment that can be kept will be listed in a treasure section.

> Nonmagical Items. Only treasure and equipment
> specifically listed under a treasure subheading can
> be kept (and converted into gp) by the characters.
> **Items not listed under a treasure subheading may be
> taken by the characters, but at the conclusion of the
> session, such items either crumble to dust, break, are
> lost, or are rendered useless—they can’t be used,
> sold, or otherwise kept.**

### From DDAL DMG

The general rule for mudane treasure

> D&D Adventurers League adventure.
> Gold and Mundane Treasure. Coin, art objects, trade
> goods, and other found wealth are converted to a gold
> piece (gp) value at the conclusion of a session, episode,
> or adventure, which is then divided by the number of
> characters in the party. Each character should earn an
> equal share unless otherwise specified. **As a general rule,
> items and treasure can’t be awarded unless it is
> described under a ‘Treasure’ subheading.**

The following indicates similar ruling for magic items.

> A permanent magic item can only be
> awarded if it, or the random magic item table it’s rolled
> from, is mentioned in the encounter in which it is found.

Since the scepter is not mentioned as treasure nor awarded from a table, it cannot be kept or sold after the adventure.